# How does a reverse while loop know when to stop in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, while-loop

In JavaScript, I have recently came across how reverse while loops are faster.

I have seen them in this form:

```
var i = someArray.length;

while (i--) {
  console.log(someArray[i]);
}
```

I tested this out and it stopped once it went through the whole array.

How does it know when to stop once it completes the array?

Comment: an [article](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/) in case you want to know what "truthiness" is.

Comment: @OnesimusUnbound yeah that article helps ALOT, thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A while loop evaluates the expression inside the parentheses each time through the loop.  When that expression gets to a falsey value, the loop will stop.

Examples of falsey values are:

```
false 
0  
undefined  
NaN
null
""
```

In this case the value of `i` will be decremented each time through the loop and when it hits the value of `0`, the loop will stop.  Because it's a post decrement operator, the value of the expression is checked before the decrement.  This means that the inner loop will see values of `i` from `someArray.length - 1` to `0` (inclusive) which are all the indexes of that array.

Your code example:

```
var i = someArray.length;

while (i--) {
    console.log(someArray[i]);
}
```

creates the same output as this:

```
for (var i = someArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    console.log(someArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: Those examples are all of them :)

Answer (score 6):

When `i--` reaches 0, the loop stops.

The loop stops once the expression in `while ( ... )` evaluates to false.
Since `i` is a positive number (length), and decreasing, it will reach zero at some point.

In a boolean context, zero translates to `false`, ensuring that the loop stops at some point.
Because `i--` returns the value prior decrement, `i` is actually `-1` when the loop stops.

Comment: It is not quite correct to say that 'zero equals false', better to say that 0 evaluates to false.

Comment: Zero does not exist in a boolean context, strictly speaking. What's happening is that the [abstract `ToBoolean` function](http://es5.github.com/#x9.2) converts `0` to `false`.

Comment: In a JS boolean context ("world"), we have only two values: `true` and `false` (that's my interpretation of the word "context"). Did I miss anything here?

Comment: It looks like we're talking on different wavelengths. If only `true` and `false` exist in boolean context and nothing else (as you say), it does not make sense to introduce zero in that context, does it?

Comment: @pimvdb Now, I see your issue. I meant: "Zero, used in a boolean context, translates to false." (Method("Zero") = `false`, hence my "zero equals false in a boolean context" statement).

Answer (score 1):

Every time the loop runs, `i--` is checked. The `--` tells Javascript to decrement `i` by 1. Eventually, `i` will get down to 0, which is equivalent to `false`. At this point, the loop stops.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a stab in the dark it's because 0 evaluates to false in a boolean expression.
0 == true returns false
0 == false returns true

Notice how if you start at -1 it will loop endlessly.

Answer (score 0):

The while loop stops evaluating once it reaches a falsy value. 
0 is a falsy value, which happens to be the first index of the array.
The reason why the for loop still loops while the "i" is 0 is because when you do a decrement expression the return value is the actually the value of the variable before the operation.

```
let i = 10;
let j = i--

console.log(i) // 9
console.log(j) // 10
```

so when your while loop gets to 1 and then the condition in the for loop decrements "--" the i variable the return value is 1, which is truthy but in fact when the rest of you loop accesses i the value of it is 0.